# The lifespan of a question

Tags: discussion

I've noticed that after ~ 1 day of asking a question, the chance of a response (answers or comments) drops to almost zero. This is fine if the question has been resolved but not so good if the question remains 'active' (hasn't received an answer or an accepted answer). Aside from placing a bounty on the question, what else can be done to attract attention a) from the point of the question asker and b) from the point of Stack Overflow i.e. provide more filtering options on the list of questions etc?

Comment: in regard to a) if the question can be improved then doing so will bump it to the top of "active"

Comment: Give the question a better title to attract the right attention right away because depending on the tags you use it could be competing in a field that receives ~1 question per minute. Some people say this site is going downhill due to an onslaught of garbage questions so make sure yours is not one of them. **[Read More](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late)**

Comment: In that case, maybe the garbage questions need to be addressed? Or more specifically, the garbage users?

Comment: You're preaching to the choir my man. Feel free to weigh in on the larger issues at hand especially ones regarding moderation tactics. Kudos for taking an interest in this community :)

Comment: Other sites on the **[StackExchange network](http://stackexchange.com/sites)** are not affected by this plague yet but I am pretty sure that it's creeping up at **http://superuser.com/**

Comment: @MonkeyZeus will do! I'll head over to the debate now and have a read... Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: No problem! There are actually several good, active discussions on this broader topic so if I come across more that I've found then I will try and remember to link you to them. Also this is my personal favorite answer: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252077/2191572

Comment: Funny, that is the answer I read to begin with! Completely agree with the 4 camps of user although I think there is a case for a 5th camp - I'd call them phantom users - they ask a single low-quality question never to be seen again.

Comment: ... "Meaningful" ...*ahem*.. . edits will bounce you back to FP. You know, how you want to change that not-so-sophisticated wording to be ... slightly less not-so-sophisticated? Well, that's what I do. Of course, eventually you may run into it being "community wiki" - but we want answers !!!

Comment: @Coffee I think editing for the sake of bumping is frowned upon?

Comment: @henrywright - Touche, I should log off meta for today. too much sarcasm

Answer (score 3):

- like you said, place a bounty
- go to a tag/programming language specific room on chat.SO that fits your question and ask if anyone wants to answer your question
- improve your question by editing it which will move it to the top of the *active* page

As to what SO could do.. well I think they already provide a lot of filtering, features to help like the 3 I listed above and others. Not sure what else they could realistically do to help get your question more attention without annoying users

Comment: *Note*: Edits are helpful, but don't edit purely for the sake of getting attention.